# \textit doesn't work with babel’s russian and mathptmx

Tags: babel, italic, cyrillic, times

`\textit` doesn't work in a LaTeX template for a thesis in English. Now I am writing my thesis in Russian using the same template. MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}      
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\begin{document}
оценка эвапотранспирации тростника обыкновенного
\textit{(Phragmites Australis)}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While I have no idea where your problem comes from and I’ve never needed to typeset Russian, replacing `mathptmx` with [`newtxmath`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/newtxmath) seems to fix it. The [times](/questions/tagged/times) tag wiki gave me the idea, and while I usually don’t typeset math (and if I did, I wouldn’t use Times), `newtxmath` seems to be intended as a successor for `mathptmx`.

```
\documentclass{article}      
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\begin{document}
оценка эвапотранспирации тростника обыкновенного
\textit{(Phragmites Australis)}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

P.S.: This also works with the configuration of your initial MWE.

P.P.S.: Someone more knowledgable in these kinds of font issues might be able to give you a solution without switching packages.

Comment: No, it doesn't work for me :( Can it be bacause of my documentclass is not article, it is thesis?

Comment: @Sasha If I replace `article` with `thesis` (all lowercase) in my code, it still works. Is the `thesis` class you’re using a custom class? Or do you get any error messages if you compile my code? MWE stands for _Minimal Working Example_ and basically means the least amount of code necessary to reproduce a problem. For some more information, see [I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: Sorry I forgot to tell. Yes, when I compile your code I have error message: newtxmath.sty not found. I guess the thesis class is a custom class. I can give a link to the template I am using.

Comment: @Sasha Actually these two factors are not related, so it doesn’t have to be custom. Do you know how to install a package in your LaTeX distribution? If yes, install `newtxmath`. If not, do you use MiKTeX or TeX Live (on which operating system) or something else?

Comment: No, I don't know how to install it. I use TexLive 2009, Windows xp. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Sasha Ah, that package might not even be available for TeX Live 2009, I’m not sure. If possible, I’d recommend uninstalling TL 2009 and installing TL 2012. If you do the full install, `newtxmath` should work right away.

Comment: Ok, I understand. Many thanks! Also, would be useful for me to know how to install a package in LaTex distribution (in the future). Please.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7273/discussion-between-doncherry-and-sasha)

Comment: The difference between `newtxmath` and `mathptmx` here is that the latter tries to use the font Times (`ptm`) for text. But it is not available in `T2A` encoding, the mechanism of font substitution uses Computer Modern for upright, but tries to substitute Times upright in `T2A` for Times italic in `T2A`. None of them is available (TeXLive 2012).

Comment: @jfbu You’re right. So I assume the way to go would be to install `mathptmx` manually, along the lines of e.g. [Where do I place my own .sty files, to make them available to all my .tex files?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1137)?

Comment: @doncherry: well, if `mathptmx` is wanted for math, one just needs to add after loading it `\def\rmdefault{cmr}` to counteract its `\def\rmdefault{ptm}`. Because everything else in `mathptmx.sty` is math mode only.